# How to configure Nutch to expand zip files and send the contents to Solr

Tags: solr, nutch, apache-tika

I'm using Nutch (2.2.1) to crawl and index a set of web pages. These pages contain many .zip files, and each .zip contains many documents.  I'll be searching the crawled data with Solr (4.7), and, within Solr, I'd like each document (within each zip) to have its own record.

Can anyone suggest a good way to set this up?

Is it possible to decompress .zip files in Nutch, and to get Nutch send multiple records to Solr, one for each file inside the .zip?  If so, how?  Would I need to write a plugin, or can this be done through configuration options alone?

On the other hand, would it make more sense to expand and index the zip files outside of Nutch, using a separate app?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!